# Vue js Error in getter for computedItems vuetify

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm not very used to Vue Js and I am implementing a search through an input  in a Vuetify table. The object containing the items of the table is in a computed property and when I start typing I get this error.

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNim0.png)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4QYz.png)

I am using a different structure than the one used by the default component in the documentation for searches to allow filtering by more fields.

**Component:**

```html
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <ConfigurationDialog :show="showConfigurationDialog" @close-configuration="handleCloseConfiguration" />
        <transition appear name="custom" appear-active-class="animated zoomIn" :duration="2000">
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-card class="text-center" dark color="primary">
                        <v-card-title class="display-2">Jornadas</v-card-title>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="8">
                    <v-col cols="12" style="text-align: center;">
                        <span class="display-1 primary--text">Resumen</span>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-card style="text-align: center; min-height: 60px; padding-top: 5px;">
                            <loading
                                :active="pendingRequest"
                                :can-cancel="false"
                                :is-full-page="false"
                                color="#3C4A66"
                                :height="50"
                            ></loading>
                            <v-card-text v-show="!pendingRequest">
                                <v-icon color="primary" :size="20">mdi-pound</v-icon>&nbsp; Cantidad:
                                <b>{{ journeys.length }}</b
                                >&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <!--
                                <span v-for="indicator in summary.indicators" :key="indicator.name">
                                    <v-icon color="purple" :size="20">mdi-ruler</v-icon>&nbsp; {{ indicator.name }}:
                                    <b>{{ indicator.value + indicator.unit }}</b
                                    > &nbsp;
                                </span>-->
                                &nbsp; <v-icon color="error" :size="20">mdi-alert-box</v-icon>&nbsp; Problemas:
                                <!--<b>{{ summary.errors }}</b>-->
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; <v-icon color="warning" :size="20">mdi-alert-box-outline</v-icon>&nbsp;
                                Advertencias:
                                <!--<b>{{ summary.warnings }}</b>-->
                            </v-card-text>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="4">
                    <v-col cols="12" style="text-align: center;">
                        <span class="display-1 primary--text">Opciones</span>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-card style="min-height: 60px; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <v-btn @click="exportToExcel" color="success" class="actionButton" small fab dark>
                                <v-icon>mdi-file-excel</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                            &nbsp;
                            <!--TODO: Para agregar cuando vuelvan las configuraciones
                            <v-btn @click="handleShowConfiguration" color="primary" class="actionButton" small fab dark>
                                <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                            -->
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-card>
                        <v-row>
                            
                            <v-col cols="12">
                                <v-container fluid>
                                            <v-row>
                                                <v-col cols="3">
                                                    <v-row class="pa-3">
                                                        <v-text-field
                                                            v-model="choferFilterValue"
                                                            append-icon="search"
                                                            label="Buscar"
                                                            single-line
                                                            hide-details
                                                            @click="this.$_disableListenkey"
                                                            @blur="this.$_enableListenkey"
                                                        ></v-text-field>
                                                    </v-row>
                                                </v-col>



                                                <v-col cols="2">
                                                    <v-row class="pa-2">
                                                        <v-select
                                                            :items="availabilityList"
                                                            v-model="availabilityFilterValue"
                                                            :placeholder="'Cualquiera'"
                                                            label="Disponibilidad"
                                                    ></v-select>
                                                    </v-row>
                                                </v-col>

                                                <!-- <v-col cols="2">
                                                    <v-row class="pa-2">
                                                        <v-select
                                                            :items="journeyStatus"
                                                            :placeholder="'Todas'"
                                                            label="Estado"
                                                        ></v-select>
                                                    </v-row>
                                                </v-col> -->

                                                <v-col cols="2" style="display:flex; align-items:center">
                                                    <v-row class="pa-2" >
                                                        <v-btn small color="secondary" @click="search = ''">Quitar filtros</v-btn>
                                                    </v-row>
                                                </v-col>
                                            </v-row>
                                        </v-container>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col cols="12">
                                    <loading
                                        :active="pendingRequest"
                                        :can-cancel="false"
                                        :is-full-page="false"
                                        color="#3C4A66"
                                        :height="50"
                                    ></loading>
                                    
                                    <v-data-table :headers="computedHeaders" :items="journeys" item-key="name" class="elevation-1 pa-6">
                                        <template v-slot:item.driver="{ item }">
                                            <span>{{ item.driver.id }}</span>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-slot:item.vehicle="{ item }">
                                            <span>{{ item.vehicle.vehicle_plate }}</span>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-slot:item.datetime_from="{ item }">
                                            <span>{{ format(item.datetime_from) }}</span>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-slot:item.datetime_to="{ item }">
                                            <span>{{ format(item.datetime_to) }}</span>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-slot:item.driver.availability="{ item }">
                                            <span :class="{'success--text': item.driver.availability, 'error--text': !item.driver.availability}" v-html="(item.driver.availability ? 'DISPONIBLE' : 'NO DISPONIBLE')"></span>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-slot:item.alerts="{ item }">
                                            <v-badge style="margin-top: 10px;" color="error" left overlap v-if="item.summary.errors > 0">
                                                <template v-slot:badge >
                                                    <div class="alerts" >
                                                        {{ item.summary.errors }}
                                                    </div>
                                                </template>
                                                <v-icon color="error" :size="30">mdi-alert-box</v-icon>
                                            </v-badge>
                                            &nbsp;
                                            <v-badge color="warning" left overlap v-if="item.summary.errors > 0">
                                                <template v-slot:badge>
                                                    <div class="alerts">
                                                        {{ item.summary.warnings }}
                                                    </div>
                                                </template>
                                                <v-icon color="warning" :size="30">mdi-alert-box-outline</v-icon>
                                            </v-badge>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                                            <div class="routerLinkButton">
                                                <router-link :to="{ name: 'journey', params: { id: item.id } }"
                                                    ><v-icon color="success" :size="30">mdi-file-document</v-icon></router-link
                                                >
                                            </div>
                                        </template>
                                    </v-data-table>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </transition>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { Component, Mixins, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {
    AuthStoreHelper,
    NotificationStoreHelper,
    RootStoreHelper,
    StoreHelper,
    VehicleCompanyStoreHelper
} from '../../core/mixins';
import { JourneysService } from '../api/JourneysService';
import { FilterDateEvent } from '../../core/utils/types';
import {
    getDateFromDateFormatApi,
    formatDate,
    getDateByFormat,
    getDateTimeFromYesterday,
    getDateTimeToYesterday,
    getDateTimeToToDay,
    getDateTimeFromToDay
} from '../../core/utils';
import { TypeFilterDate } from '../../core/models/type-filter-date';
import { ConfigurationDialog } from '../components';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { JourneysListHistoricalDataResponse, journeyHistorical, journeyRT } from '../models/JourneysList';
import store, { AuthEvent, GetterType } from '../../../store';

@Component({
    components: { Loading, ConfigurationDialog }
})
export default class JourneysPage extends Mixins(
    StoreHelper,
    RootStoreHelper,
    VehicleCompanyStoreHelper,
    NotificationStoreHelper,
    AuthStoreHelper
) {
    cancelToken: any | null = null;
    showConfigurationDialog: boolean = false;
    headers: any[] = [];
    selectedFilters: any[] = [];
    dateFrom: any = null;
    dateTo: any = null;
    menuDateFrom: boolean =  false;
    menuDateTo: boolean =  false;
    modal: boolean = false;
    menu2: boolean = false;
    pendingRequest: boolean = true;
    search: string = '';
    choferFilterValue: any = '';
    availabilityFilterValue: any = '';
    sortBy: string[] = ["datetime_to", "datetime_from"];
    sortDesc: boolean[] = [false, false];
    availabilityList: any = [
        {
            text: "Disponible", 
            value: true
        },
        {
            text: "No disponible", 
            value: false
        },
        {
            text: "Cualquiera", 
            value: null
        }
    ];


    get computedHeaders(): any {
        return [
            {
                text: 'Chofer',
                align: 'left',
                value: 'driver.id',
                filter: this.choferFilter
            },
            { 
                text: 'Vehículo', 
                value: 'vehicle.vehicle_plate'
            },
            { 
                text: 'Inicio', 
                value: 'datetime_from' 
            },
            { 
                text: 'Fin', 
                value: 'datetime_to' 
            },
            { 
                text: 'Disponibilidad', 
                value: 'driver.availability',
                filter: this.availabilityFilter,
            },
            { 
                text: 'Alertas', 
                value: 'alerts', 
                sortable: false 
            },
            { 
                text: 'Acciones',
                value: 'actions', 
                sortable: false 
            }
        ]
    }

    journeyStatus: any = [
        {text: "Finalizada", value: true},
        {text: "No Finalizada", value: false},
        {text: "Cualquiera", value: null}
    ];

    headersRT: any[] = [
        {
            text: 'Chofer',
            align: 'left',
            value: 'driver.id'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Vehículo', 
            value: 'vehicle.vehicle_plate' 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Inicio', 
            value: 'datetime_from' 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Fin', 
            value: 'datetime_to' 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Disponibilidad', 
            value: 'driver.availability'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Alertas', 
            value: 'alerts', 
            sortable: false 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Acciones',
            value: 'actions', 
            sortable: false 
        }
    ];
    headersHistorical: any[] = [
        {
            text: 'Chofer',
            align: 'left',
            value: 'driver.id'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Vehículo', 
            value: 'vehicle.vehicle_plate' 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Inicio', 
            value: 'datetime_from' 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Fin', 
            value: 'datetime_to' 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Disponibilidad', 
            value: 'driver.availability'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Alertas', 
            value: 'alerts', 
            sortable: false 
        },
        { 
            text: 'Acciones',
            value: 'actions', 
            sortable: false 
        }
    ];
    summary: any = {};
    journeys: journeyHistorical[] | journeyRT[] = [];
    journeysRT: any[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            driver: {
                id: "12345678",
                availability: true,
            },
            vehicle: {
                vehicle_plate: "NOD-2580"
            },
            summary:{
                errors: 1,
                alarms: 2,
                warnings: 3
            },
            datetime_from: '10/10/19 - 4:50',
            datetime_to: 'En Curso',
            availability: false,
            alerts: [3, 2],
            actions: 5
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            driver: {
                id: "87654321",
                availability: false
            },
            vehicle: {
                vehicle_plate: "DIS-2580"
            },
            summary:{
                errors: 0,
                alarms: 0,
                warnings: 0
            },
            datetime_from: '10/10/19 - 4:50',
            datetime_to: 'En Curso',
            availability: false,
            alerts: [3, 2],
            actions: 5
        }
    ];
    journeysHistorical: any[] = [
        {
            id: 7,
            driver: 'Jorge Pérez',
            vehicle: 159,
            datetime_from: '10/10/19 - 4:50',
            datetime_to: '10/10/19 - 19:30',
            alerts: [3, 2],
            actions: 5
        }
    ];

    choferFilter(value) {
        console.log("value", value);
        console.log("this.choferFilterValue", this.choferFilterValue);
        // If this filter has no value we just skip the entire filter.
        if (!this.choferFilterValue) {
          return true;
        }

        // Check if the current loop value (The dessert name)
        // partially contains the searched word.
        return value.toLowerCase().includes(this.choferFilterValue.toLowerCase());
      }

      /**
       * Filter for calories column.
       * @param value Value to be tested.
       * @returns {boolean}
       */
      availabilityFilter(value) {
        // If this filter has no value we just skip the entire filter.
        console.log("value", value);
        console.log("this.availabilityFilterValue", this.availabilityFilterValue);
        if (!this.availabilityFilterValue) {
            console.log("if", this.availabilityFilterValue);
          return true;
        }

        // Check if the current loop value (The calories value)
        // equals to the selected value at the <v-select>.
        return value === this.availabilityFilterValue;
      }

    customFilter(items, search, filter) {
        return filter.driver.id.toString().includes(search) || filter.vehicle.vehicle_plate.includes(search.toString().toUpperCase())
    }

    customSort(items: any[], sortBy: string[], sortDesc: boolean[]) {
        items.sort(function(a, b) {
            let sorts: number[] = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < sortBy.length; i++) {
                let condition = 0;
                switch (sortBy[i]) {
                    case 'driver':
                        if (!sortDesc[i]) {
                            condition =
                                a[sortBy[i]].id == b[sortBy[i]].id ? 0 : a[sortBy[i]].id < b[sortBy[i]].id ? 1 : -1;
                        } else {
                            condition =
                                a[sortBy[i]].id == b[sortBy[i]].id ? 0 : a[sortBy[i]].id > b[sortBy[i]].id ? 1 : -1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'vehicle':
                        if (!sortDesc[i]) {
                            condition =
                                a[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate == b[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate
                                    ? 0
                                    : a[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate < b[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate
                                    ? 1
                                    : -1;
                        } else {
                            condition =
                                a[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate == b[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate
                                    ? 0
                                    : a[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate > b[sortBy[i]].vehicle_plate
                                    ? 1
                                    : -1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'datetime_from':
                        let dateFromA = getDateFromDateFormatApi(a[sortBy[i]]);
                        let dateFromB = getDateFromDateFormatApi(b[sortBy[i]]);
                        if (!sortDesc[i]) {
                            condition = dateFromA == dateFromB ? 0 : dateFromA < dateFromB ? 1 : -1;
                        } else {
                            condition = dateFromA == dateFromB ? 0 : dateFromA > dateFromB ? 1 : -1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'datetime_to':
                        let dateToA = getDateFromDateFormatApi(a[sortBy[i]]);
                        let dateToB = getDateFromDateFormatApi(b[sortBy[i]]);
                        if (!sortDesc[i]) {
                            if (a[sortBy[i]] == null && b[sortBy[i]] == null) {
                                condition = 0;
                            } else if (a[sortBy[i]] == null) {
                                condition = -1;
                            } else if (b[sortBy[i]] == null) {
                                condition = 1;
                            } else {
                                condition = dateToA == dateToB ? 0 : dateToA < dateToB ? 1 : -1;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (a[sortBy[i]] == null && b[sortBy[i]] == null) {
                                condition = 0;
                            } else if (a[sortBy[i]] == null) {
                                condition = 1;
                            } else if (b[sortBy[i]] == null) {
                                condition = -1;
                            } else {
                                condition = dateToA == dateToB ? 0 : dateToA > dateToB ? 1 : -1;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'availability':
                }
                sorts.push(condition);
            }
            let result = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < sorts.length; i++) {
                if (sorts[i] != 0) {
                    return sorts[i];
                }
            }
            return result;
        });
        return items;
    }

    handleShowConfiguration() {
        this.showConfigurationDialog = true;
    }

    handleCloseConfiguration() {
        this.showConfigurationDialog = false;
    }

    exportToExcel() {
        // A workbook is the name given to an Excel file
        let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new(); // make Workbook of Excel
        let journeys: any[] = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.journeys.length; i++) {
            let journey = {};
            journey['Chofer'] = this.journeys[i].driver;
            journey['Vehículo'] = this.journeys[i].vehicle;
            journey['Inicio'] = this.journeys[i].datetime_from;
            //journey['Fin'] = this.journeys[i].datetime_to;
            //journey['Problemas'] = this.journeys[i].alerts[0];
            //journey['Advertencias'] = this.journeys[i].alerts[1];

            journeys.push(journey);
        }
        let journeysWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(journeys);

        // Workbook contains one or more worksheets
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, journeysWS, 'Jornadas');

        XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'ListadoDeJornadas.xlsx');
    }



    @Watch('$_getFilterDate')
    @Watch('$_getSelectedVehiclesByID')
    getJourneysList() {
        this.pendingRequest = true;
        this.journeys = [];
        this.cancelToken = Axios.CancelToken.source();
        if (this.$_existVehiclesSelected()) {
            if (this.$_getFilterDate == TypeFilterDate.TR) {
                this.headers = this.headersRT;
                JourneysService.getJourneysListRT(this.$_getSelectedVehiclesByID, false, this.cancelToken).then(
                    data => {
                        this.journeys = data.journeys;
                        this.summary = data.summary;
                        this.pendingRequest = false;
                    }
                );
            } else if (this.$_getFilterDate == TypeFilterDate.TODAY) {
                this.headers = this.headersHistorical;
                JourneysService.getJourneysListHistorical(
                    getDateTimeFromToDay(),
                    getDateTimeToToDay(),
                    this.$_getSelectedVehiclesByID,
                    false,
                    this.cancelToken
                ).then(data => {
                    this.pendingRequest = false;
                });
            } else {
                this.headers = this.headersHistorical;
                JourneysService.getJourneysListHistorical(
                    getDateTimeToYesterday(),
                    getDateTimeFromYesterday(),
                    this.$_getSelectedVehiclesByID,
                    false,
                    this.cancelToken
                ).then(data => {
                    this.pendingRequest = false;
                });
            }
        } else {
            this.pendingRequest = false;
        }
    }

    mounted() {
        this.getJourneysList();
    }

    format(date: string) {
        return formatDate(date);
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.actionButton {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.alerts {
    text-align: center;
    left: -4px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
}
.routerLinkButton a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there, could you fix the code snippet please?, or could you upload your code to jsfiddle or codesandbox, it will be easier to help you checking the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem *(at least the error1)* is in `return value.toLowerCase().includes(this.choferFilterValue.toLowerCase());` , maybe the type of the value is not an array/string to use includes.

Can u do: `console.log(typeof value)`?, you should also check that never is passed an undefined value/ null, maybe that cause an error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I’ll check that. Thanks